# mutagen read TemporaryUploadedFile in django

Tags: python, django, mutagen

I want to validate my mp3s before saving them to disk, using Mutagen. However with mutagen I can only open a file if it's on disk. Is there a way around this? I would like to be able to do this:

```
files = request.FILES
mp3 = files.get('mp3')
mp3_audio = MP3(mp3)
```

Gives me the error:

```
TypeError: invalid file: <TemporaryUploadedFile: test.mp3 (audio/mpeg)>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `TemporaryUploadedFile` file object is already on disk, in a directory reserved for temp files.  To analyze it for validity, call a method to get the full path:

```
files = request.FILES
mp3_temp = files.get('mp3')
mp3_audio = MP3(mp3_temp.temporary_file_path())
```

see docs at [TemporaryUploadedFile.temporary_file_path()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile.temporary_file_path)

Comment: Whoa, if I had known about this feature I would have saved myself so many frustrating moments.

Comment: Hey again, for some reason django is now no longer returning a TemporaryUploadedFile, but instead a InMemoryFile. Any ideas? It just started happening on random, and on certain files.

Comment: nvm, had to remove the memory file handler in settings